# Create field that stores multiple doc/img in single filed using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How to create field that stores multiple document/images in single field using React?

```
export const DemoimgUpdate = () => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
  const demoimgEntity = useAppSelector(state => state.demoimg.entity);
  const loading = useAppSelector(state => state.demoimg.loading);
  const updating = useAppSelector(state => state.demoimg.updating);
  const updateSuccess = useAppSelector(state => state.demoimg.updateSuccess);

  const handleClose = () => {
    navigate('/demoimg' + location.search);
  };

  const defaultValues = () => isNew
    ? {}
    : { ...demoimgEntity };

  return (
    <ValidatedForm defaultValues={defaultValues()} onSubmit={saveEntity}>
      {!isNew
        ? <ValidatedField
            name="id"
            required
            readOnly
            id="demoimg-id"
            label="ID"
            validate={{ required: true }}
          />
        : null
      }
      <ValidatedBlobField
        label="Images"
        id="demoimg-images" 
        name="images"
        data-cy="images"
        isImage
        accept="image/*"
        multiple
      />
```